# Returning the ticket ID after creating a new ticket with JIRA api via C#

Tags: c#, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using below SDK to interact with JIRA via C#,

https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home

Ticket creation is successful and the response is shown in the console mentioning the ticket ID, but I cannot find a way to load the ticket ID to a variable.

```
        var settings = new JiraRestClientSettings()
        {
            EnableRequestTrace = true
        };

        var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient("https://testjira.xxxxxxxx.com/", 
        jiraUsername, jiraPWD, settings);

        var issue = jira.CreateIssue("TMS");
        issue.Type = "Service Desk Incident";
        issue.Summary = "Test issue created via API 3";
        issue.Description = "Test issue created via API 3";
        issue["Service Desk Priority"] = "Level 3";

        await issue.SaveChangesAsync();
```

All I need to do is to capture this ID in a variable.
Thanks in advance :)

[Error message in the console when credentials are wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QciUB.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code in [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/1ef4bafb77c90598f483b1aaf13a3c301a6b9399/Atlassian.Jira/Issue.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), it can be seen that, it returns an `Issue` object

```
public async Task<Issue> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
```

So, all you need is:

```
var jiraIssue = await issue.SaveChangesAsync();
```

`jiraIssue.Key` is your newly created Key.

Comment: Thanks @subbu, it works :) one more thing,  how can I check if it returns errors, for an example if the username or password is wrong, how to get that error message and load it to a string? Or at least identify that ticket creation was not successful. Errors are shown in the console, but they are messy. Check the screenshot attached to the question.